# Flutter how to use a class in my functtion

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new with Flutter.
I have a function that keeps all elements by type that have the distance closest to a certain value.
So I want a list of elements that all have a different type and that for each type the distance value is the closest to my value entered as a parameter.

It works when I not use a class but now I want to use my class but it not works ...

**My function who works without class:**

```
function getItemsValid(List items, int distance){
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> _lastDistanceByItems = items
        .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
        .fold(<int, Map<String, dynamic>>{}, (Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> map, item)
    {
      final int _type = item['type'];
      if (distance <= item['distance']) map[_type] = {"type" : item['type']};
      return map;
    }).values.toList();
}
```

**My function with my class NOT WORKS:**

```
function getItemsValid(List items, int distance){
    List<Item> _lastDistanceByItems = items
        .cast<Item>()
        .fold(<int, Item>{}, (Map<int, Item> map, item)
    {
      final int _type = item.type;
      if (distance <= item.distance) map[_type] = {"type" : item.type}; // This not works
      return map;
    }).values.toList();
}
```

**My class Item:**

```
class Item{
  int type;
  int distance;

  Item({
    this.type,
    this.distance,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'type': type.toString(),
    'distance': distance.toString(),
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ '
        '${this.type}, '
        '${this.distance}, '
        '}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `cast` to arbitrarily convert a collection of `Map` objects into `Item` objects. That's not how `cast` works - it takes a list of broadly-typed objects and converts it into a list of more narrowly-typed objects. For example, if you had a `List<dynamic>` where you knew every object inside was a string, you could do `cast<String>()` to convert it into `List<String>`. However, if there is an object that is *not* a string in the list, that will result in an error.

Instead, you want to use `map` to explicitly define the conversion between a `Map` object and an `Item` object. The first step is to define a `fromJson` constructor in your `Item` class:

```dart
class Item {
  ...
  
  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) : this(
    type: map['type'], 
    distance: map['distance'],
  );
}
```

Using this constructor, so the implementation of the `map` function is simple:

```dart
List<Item> _lastDistanceByItems = items
    .map((elem) => Item.fromJson(elem))
```

After that, the call to `fold` should work just fine.